# Warning: require_once(bootstrap/app.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\laragon\www\halfproject\public\index.php

Tags: laravel

I don't know why I have this error and I have googled it 
but found nothing can s.b help me?
I know what this error says
it can't find `app.php` in `index.php` but don't know how to add it.

Comment: did you just install laravel  ? or it is already setup ?

Comment: I checked my bootstrap folder was deleted I dont know why.do u know?

Comment: Is it working after `composer install` ?

Answer (score 0):

You might unfortunately delete your bootstrap files from the root directory. For me, I have installed a new fresh laravel with the same name as my current project. And Then copy that bootstrap file into my original project root path. Hope that will work.